# String to integer implicit change when not called for?

Tags: python, encryption, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a simple encryption/decryption code in Python like this (maybe you can see what I'm going for):

```
def encrypt():
    import random
    input1 = input('Write Text: ')
    input1 = input1.lower()
    key = random.randint(10,73)
    output = []
    for character in input1:
        number = ord(character) - 96
        number = number + key
        output.append(number)
    output.insert(0,key)
    print (''.join(map(str, output)))
def decrypt():
    text = input ('What to decrypt?')
    key = int(text[0:2])
    text = text[2:]
    n=2
    text = text
    text = [text[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(text), n)]
    text = map(int,text)
    text = [x - key for x in text]
    text = ''.join(map(str,text))
    text = int(text)
    print (text)
    for character in str(text):
        output = []
        character = int((character+96))
        number = str(chr(character))
        output.append(number)
    print (''.join(map(str, output)))
```

When I run the decryptor with the output from the encryption output, I get "TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly."

As you can see, I've added some redundancies to help try to fix things but nothing's working. I ran it with different code (can't remember what), but all that one kept outputting was something like "generatorobject at ."

I'm really lost and I could use some pointers guys, please and thank you.

EDIT: The problem arises on line 27.

EDIT 2: Replaced "character = int((character+96))" with "character = int(character)+96", now the problem is that it only prints (and as I can only assume) only appends the last letter of the decrypted message.

EDIT 2 SOLVED: output = [] was in the for loop, thus resetting it every time. Problem solved, thank you everyone!

Comment: Full traceback, please.

Comment: `text = text` - why would you do this?

Comment: Ah yes, that was another thought to fix the problem that never got finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full traceback would help, but it looks like `character = int(character)+96` is what you want on line 27.

Comment: Perhaps `character = chr(ord(character) + 96) is what the OP intended. (Then, get rid of the number= line.

Comment: Please refer to edit 2 now, I seemed to have botched it up again.